# Opening a link to a pdf when clicking a path in a d3.js donut chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a donut chart that I've created in d3. Within my csv file used to create the donut chart, I have a link to a pdf that I would like to have opened when a section of the donut chart is clicked.

My Data is formatted like so:

```
label,value,link
"Regional Water Supply",468000000,"n-wdp/funding_tables/regional_water_supply_funding.pdf"
"Municipal Water Supply",214100000,"n-wdp/funding_tables/municipal_water_supply_funding.pdf" 
"Flood Control",121300000,"n-wdp/funding_tables/flood_control_funding.pdf"
"Rural Water Supply",108500000,"n-wdp/funding_tables/rural_water_supply_funding.pdf" 
"Conveyance (Bank Stabilization, Drains, Snagging & Clearing)",88700000,"n-wdp/funding_tables/conveyance_funding.pdf"
"General Water Management",48100000,"n-wdp/funding_tables/general_water_supply_funding.pdf"
```

relevant code parts

```
var dataSum = d3.sum(data, d=> d.value);

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([domain])
    .range(colorRange)

const pie = d3.pie()
    .value(d=>d.value)
        
var dataSet = pie(data);

selection
    .selectAll('slicesShadows')
    .data(dataSet)
    .join('path')
    .attr('d', d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(radius)
    )
    .attr('fill', d => color(d.data))
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("opacity", 0.7)
    .style('filter', 'url(#blur)')
    ;
```

I've tried creating an  element, and appending my paths to that element, but it doesn't seem to allow me to click them as a link and doesn't allow me to add different links for each shape.

I also created on onClick event, but got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this myself by adding an .on('click') event to my object.

```
selection
    .selectAll('slicesShadows')
    .data(dataSet)
    .join('path')
    .attr('d', d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(radius)
    )
    .attr('fill', d => color(d.data))
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("opacity", 0.7)
    .style('filter', 'url(#blur)')
    .on('click', mouseClick)
    ;
```

and creating this mouseClick function

```
const mouseClick = (e,d) =>{
window.open(d.data.link, '_blank');
}
```

I did also have to reformat the address of the links in my data as well. Posting this answer because it was an easy fix, but I could not find an example anywhere.